# Can't get int value from a class function in PHP using Swig

Tags: php, c++, swig

I've generated a PHP wrapper around several C++ classes, but I'm hitting an error with a function that returns an unsigned integer:

This is the code in PHP (using PHP 7.3.0):

```
$results = new Results($client->get_logger());

$client->key_value_set_string($results, "shape", "triangle", true);

$status_code = $results->get_status_code();
```

Trying to print $status_code gives:

```
Resource id #9
```

var_dump($status_code) gives:

```
resource(9) of type (_p_uint8)
```

The definitions of the uint8 type and the function in the C++ header file:

```
typedef uint8_t uint8;
uint8 get_status_code();
```

Any idea why I'm getting Resource id# 9 instead of an int value? I've got this working in Python and Java SWIG wrapped code, it's just the PHP 7 code that has a problem.

Comment: Which Swig version are you using?

Comment: Swig version 3.0.12.

Comment: Solved this by changing the type to an unsigned int.